# How to check checkbox using Vue.js 2 depending on the concrete value?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to implement roles and permissions system in my application. I'm using Vue.js2 as a frontend and Laravel 5.4 as a backend.

**Here's `allRoles` array with an all roles from db:**

```
data: {
    // ...
    allRoles: [],
    userInfo: {
        id: null,
        fullname: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
        created_at: '',
        roles: [],
        permissions: []
    },
    // ...
},
```

**Here's the method of getting user info, where I'm filling in the `allRoles` array.**

```
getUserInfo(user_id) {
    this.infoLoading = true;
    axios.get(`/api/users/info/${user_id}`)
       .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);   
          if(response.status === 200) {
              this.userInfo.id            = response.data.user.id;
              this.userInfo.fullname      = response.data.user.fullname;
              this.userInfo.email         = response.data.user.email;
              this.userInfo.phone         = response.data.user.phone;
              this.userInfo.created_at    = response.data.user.created_at;
              this.userInfo.roles         = response.data.user.roles;
              this.userInfo.permissions   = response.data.user.permissions;  
              this.updateUserInfoButton   = true;
              this.allRoles               = response.data.allRoles;
              this.allPermissions         = response.data.allPermissions;
          }
          this.infoLoading = false;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
}
```

**And here the markup where I'm trying to check the checkbox:**

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success" v-for="role in allRoles">
    <div v-for="singleRole in userInfo.roles" :key="singleRole.id">
        <input :id="role.name" type="checkbox" :value="role.id" v-model="userInfo.roles" :checked="singleRole.name.includes(role.name) ? 'true' : 'false'">
        <label :for="role.name">@{{ role.display_name }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately I'm getting not checked checkboxes. How should I properly do that? What's the workaround?

Comment: Is `response.data.user.roles` definitely an array of ids? Can you show your Route/Controller code for `/api/users/info/${user_id}`?

Comment: @RossWilson yeah the response is an array of ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you what you are trying to do is list all roles, and have user's roles checked and update `userInfo.roles` at the same time, then this should work as long as `userInfo.roles` contains roles' ids:

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/24424/

template (I've changed yours slightly, because when I used yours, all inputs appeared twice. Also you don't need to use both `:checked` and `v-model`):

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-success" v-for="role in allRoles">
     <input :id="role.name" type="checkbox" :value="role.id" v-model="userInfo.roles">
     <label :for="role.name">@{{ role.name }}</label>
  </div> 
  {{userInfo.roles}}
</div>
```

vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    allRoles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test_role'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'another_role'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'pizza eater'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'peanuts eater'
      }
    ],
    userInfo: {
        id: null,
        fullname: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
        created_at: '',
        roles: [1, 3],
        permissions: []
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: is that okay if I'm trying to render the roles after `axios` call? Because from the start `userInfo.roles` is empty...

Comment: could you show a log of `response.data`? The code above should work as long as `userInfo.roles` is assigned correctly.